select with condition fromselect with condition from 3 tables mysql 3 tables mysql
I have 3 table like these :
Table A 
-------------------------------------------------------------
    id       name         number        category
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1        apple          5             F
    2        orange         1             F
    3        ball           2             X
    4        banana         10            F
    


Table B 
-------------------------------------------------------------
    id        name          number       confirm
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1         apple            5           yes
    1         apple            1           no
    4         banana           2           yes
    4         banana           1           yes


Table C
-------------------------------------------------------------
    id        name          number         confirm
-------------------------------------------------------------
    2         orange           2              yes
    4         banana           2              no

I want to search in all tables and return results with this conditions :
if Table A.category = 'F'   return (id and name an number)  else return nothing

if Table B.confirm or Table C.confirm = 'Yes'  return SUM(number)  else return 0

in this case results must be like this:
-------------------------------------------------------------
id           name            A       B       C
-------------------------------------------------------------
1            apple           5       5       0
2            orange          1       0       2
4            banana          10      3       0

thank you

What did you try to do? What is your question?

WITH     -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
  TABLE_A  (id, name, number, category) AS
    ( Select   1, 'apple',   5, 'F'  Union All
      Select   2, 'orange',  1, 'F'  Union All
      Select   3, 'ball',    2, 'X' Union All
      Select   4, 'banana', 10, 'F'
    ),
  TABLE_B  (id, name, number, confirm) AS
    ( Select   1, 'apple',  5, 'yes' Union All
      Select   1, 'apple',  1, 'no'  Union All
      Select   4, 'banana', 2, 'yes' Union All
      Select   4, 'banana', 1, 'yes'
    ),
  TABLE_C  (id, name, number, confirm) AS
    ( Select   2, 'orange', 2, 'yes' Union All
      Select   4, 'banana', 2, 'no'
    )  

Left join tables B and C to table A use Case Expressions for conditional aggregation (Sum), filter the resultset with Where clause and Group by on non-aggregated columns...
--     S Q L :  
Select      a.id, a.name,
            a.number as A,
            Sum( Case When b.confirm = 'yes' Then  b.number Else 0 End) as B,
            Sum( Case When c.confirm = 'yes' Then  c.number Else 0 End) as C
From        TABLE_A a
Left  Join  TABLE_B b ON ( b.id = a.id )
Left  Join  TABLE_C c ON ( c.id = a.id )
Where       a.category = 'F'
Group By    a.id, a.name, a.number
Order By    a.id

/*   R e s u l t :
id  name     A   B   C
--  ------- --  --  --
 1  apple    5   5   0
 2  orange   1   0   2
 4  banana  10   3   0  */

See the fiddle here.
